# acronym - tabular -- weird spacing while using \ac

Tags: tables, spacing, acronyms

I'm currently writing a Lab-Report, using a lot of acronyms and tables.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pH}{pH}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}%
    \begin{tabular}{cp{26em}}
        \toprule%
        Lösung & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Beschreibung} \\%
        \midrule%
        1 & \SI{0.1}{\textsc{n}-Acetatpuffer} \pH \SI{5.0}{} : \SI{70.5}{\milli\liter}
        \SI{1}{\Molar} \ch{NaOH +}\SI{100}{\milli\liter} \SI{1}{\Molar} Essigsäure, auf
        \SI{1}{\liter} mit destilliertem Wasser auffüllen.\\%        
        2 &\acl{tcl}--Lösung \SI{0.38}{\gram\per\liter} in \ac{dmso} bzw.
        \SI{189}{\milli\gram} auf \SI{5}{\milli\liter}\\%    
        3 &\ac{act}--Lösung \SI{37.8}{\milli\gram\per\milli\liter} in
        \SI{1}{\milli\Molar} \ch{HCl} bzw. \SI{189}{\milli\gram} auf
        \SI{5}{\milli\liter}\\%         
        \bottomrule%
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After changing `\ac` to `\acl` and (`\acs`) it works fine:

```
\begin{document}%
    \begin{tabular}{cp{26em}}
        \toprule%
        Lösung & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Beschreibung} \\%
        \midrule%
        1 & \SI{0.1}{\textsc{n}-Acetatpuffer} \pH \SI{5.0}{} : \SI{70.5}{\milli\liter}
        \SI{1}{\Molar} \ch{NaOH +}\SI{100}{\milli\liter} \SI{1}{\Molar} Essigsäure, auf
        \SI{1}{\liter} mit destilliertem Wasser auffüllen.\\%        
        2 &\acl{tcl}--Lösung \SI{0.38}{\gram\per\liter} in \ac{dmso} bzw.
        \SI{189}{\milli\gram} auf \SI{5}{\milli\liter}\\%    
        3 &\acl{act}--Lösung (\acs{act}) \SI{37.8}{\milli\gram\per\milli\liter} in
        \SI{1}{\milli\Molar} \ch{HCl} bzw. \SI{189}{\milli\gram} auf
        \SI{5}{\milli\liter}\\%         
        \bottomrule%
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I found a workaround, but still I would like to know what causes this problem.

I'm including this standalone in my main document, therefore its not a problem those acronyms aren't defined.

Comment: Why are you defining `\pH` as a unit when you're loading `chemmacros` which provides `\pH`?

Comment: @cgnieder: Oh, looks like I defined it before I considered using the `chemmacros` package and forgot to remove it.

Comment: there's an easy fix: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and then `\preto\ac{\leavevmode}`. Why the spacing is affected if it's missing I don't know. BTW: I'd change `\SI{0.1}{\textsc{n}-Acetatpuffer}` into `\SI{0.1}{\normal} Acetatpuffer`

Comment: @cgnieder One must be cautious about using `etoolbox` for patching `acronym` macros, because the package uses `suffix`. Nonetheless, in this case it works. Note that the problem doesn't show when the acronym is not typeset in expanded form.

Comment: @cgnieder Would you add an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\ac` command misses to leave vertical mode (which it should as it *is* going to typeset something). A quick fix is to load [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and to add

```
\preto\ac{\leavevmode}
```

to the preamble. Although this works one must be cautious using `etoolbox`'s patching with `acronym`'s commands as they are defined with the help of the [`suffix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/suffix) package which might cause the patching to fail. One could also “patch” `\ac` without another package ([as proposed by @egreg in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9924475#9924475)):

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\ac\expandafter{\expandafter\leavevmode\ac}
```

This redefines `\ac` to the first expansion of `\ac` with a `\leavevmode` added in front.