# Preventing page break after sectioning when body begins with a command?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, acronyms

I use the `acro` package heavily in my thesis, but I noticed that one section has a page break right after the section header. This appears to be a result of the first paragraph beginning with `\Ac{}` from the `acro` package. I know I could find some manual way to stop it (e.g., `\clearpage` right before the section header) but I don't want to do this, as the length of the document changes as I write/edit and this header won't always straddle the page (and new headers might straddle pages later). Is there a general fix for this problem? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{TAFTS}{short=TAFTS, long=test acronym for \TeX{} Stackexchange}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Filler Text}
Lorem \\ 
ipsum \\ 
dolor \\ 
sit \\ 
amet, \\ 
consectetur \\ 
adipiscing \\ 
elit. \\ 
Aenean \\ 
eu \\ 
faucibus \\ 
orci, \\ 
interdum \\ 
mattis \\ 
metus. \\
Pellentesque 

\section{Example}\label{sec:example}
\subsection{The Sub-Example}\label{sec:the-sub-example}
\Ac{TAFTS} placed at the beginning of a sentence causes an inappropriate page break.
How can I prevent this without messing up the spacing between my subsection and 

On the next page, you'll see that this does not happen if the paragraph does \emph{not} begin with the \texttt{\textbackslash{}Ac} command
\chapter{How it Should Work}
\section{Filler Text}
Lorem \\ 
ipsum \\ 
dolor \\ 
sit \\ 
amet, \\ 
consectetur \\ 
adipiscing \\ 
elit. \\ 
Aenean \\ 
eu \\ 
faucibus \\ 
orci, \\ 
interdum \\ 
mattis \\ 
metus. \\
Pellentesque 

\section{Example of Proper Page-Breaking}
\subsection{The Good Sub-Example}
If I start with regular text and then insert my \acf{TAFTS}, the page breaks \emph{before} my new section.
I want this to happen with the text from section~\ref{sec:example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is caused by a missing `\leavevmode` in the definition of `\Ac`. I believe that the author of `acro` is already aware of the problem. In the meantime, use `\leavevmode\Ac{TAFTS}` if the acronym is at the start of a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg This works. I also found that \mbox{\Ac{TAFTS}} does the trick as well, but I think your answer is more "proper".  I think it should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The fixed version 1.3c is already on CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/acro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one in [acronym - tabular -- weird spacing while using \ac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119410/acronym-tabular-weird-spacing-while-using-ac) although the package used there is `acronym`.

The problem is in both cases a missing `\leavevmode` when the expanded form of the acronym is used. However there's no simple patch as suggested for the similar problem with `acronym`, because `acro` is based on `expl3`.

The package author should already be aware of the problem, so a fix will be available soon. In the meantime you can overcome the problem by saying

```
\leavevmode\Ac{TAFTS}
```

when `\Ac` is at the start of a paragraph.

**Note** According to what [cgnieder said in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9980314#9980314), your example works as expected with version 1.3c that's already on CTAN, so it's a matter of hours that it finds its way in the TeX distributions.

Comment: Indeed, I just ran a MixTeX update and my example (and more importantly, my thesis) have correct page breaks without the \leavevmode command.